# Weird iis issue site doesnt opening displaying strange characters

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

Guys Have you seen this before?

I have 2 sites. A site and B Site. I add new ip to B site with Dns manager then A site effected from this. When I run A site Page gives me this please help :(

[image]

Comment: It's encoding problem, encoding in http header and content differ. Use UTF-8 encoding everywhere

Comment: Actually it was Windows Firewall. I've disabled and it works